# How do I know which Twitter apps are adding new follows to my profile?

Tags: twitter, follow

I've been getting some new **follows** (not followers) from time to time that is really disturbing my followers to following ratio. I suspect some of the apps that I authorized are doing this. I just need to know which. (I have lots of authorized apps and this doesn't seem like an easy task.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to apps in the settings, 
You can't directly identify which. What you can do:

1. You have to check for the apps with permission write, only these apps can manipulate your account in this regard.
2. Also use the browser find to search the word follower in the apps section, if you are lucky the apps which do this thing use the word follow or follower somewhere in the title or description. And revoke access from the apps which says follow or follower.
3. And if nothing above written works, You have to revoke access from all the apps having write permission.(Will definitely work)

   Tedious, but can work.

Comment: Thanks for the little pointers! Meanwhile, I think twitter really should change the way they present the permissions.